# AdjustPan not working

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app I would like to cover part of the layout when soft keyboard is open.

I've tried to use this code in my manifest, as suggested in many StackOverflow questions:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

But it didn't work, and items in my gridview are still pushed up.

**EDIT**
Here's my layout: http://pastebin.com/U2SjNLeV

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you provide xml of your layout?

Comment: @KinnarVasa question updated

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your layout with a ScrollView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >  
...

...

</ScrollView>
```